# Need to add C wire for WIFI stat

Tags: hvac

I currently have a 4 wire system and want to add a WIFI Stat which as we know needs a C wire. The current wire was an 8 strand cable so I already have the wire to hook up. I think I know where, but hoping someone is more knowledgeable on it. In the photo, where the blue and red wire are hooked, I think is the C terminal I need. Thanks in advance for your help. [image][image][image][image]

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram for your furnace please?

Comment: And a straight on shot of the terminal board and maybe a description of any embossed lettering?

Answer (score 1):

Of the two lower screws on the tan panel one is already connected to your thermostat, the other one is he C terminal.  (probably the left one is C)

[image]

in a typical extra-low voltage thermostat system a transformer provides 24V AC , one terminal goes to the thermostat and the other terminal (called common or "C" ) goes to the relays and solenoids that control control the equipment,  that shiny thing looks like a 24V doorbell transformer and the tan panel is mounted over the output terminals, so the terminal with most wires is almost certainly "C"
[image]